# Non-positive-definite quadratic program minimum simplification

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-optimization, quadratic-programming

I was finding the minimum of a simple quadratic program with equality constraints:

$$
m = \min_x x^TQx\qquad\mathrm{s.t.}\quad Ax=b.
$$

Using a formulation with Lagrange multipliers [from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_programming#Equality_constraints) I was able to find the closed-form minimizer $x^*$ from
$$
\left(\begin{array}{c}x^* \\ \lambda^*\end{array}\right) =
\left(\begin{array}{cc}Q & A^T \\ A & 0\end{array}\right)^{-1}
\left(\begin{array}{c}0 \\ b\end{array}\right).
$$
Using block-wise matrix inversion for the inverse here and pushing everything through gives:
$$
x^* = Q^{-1}A^T(AQ^{-1}A^T)^{-1}b 
$$

and, from that, that the minimum is $$m = b^T(AQ^{-1}A^T)^{-1}b.$$

The above requires, though, that $Q$ be positive-definite.

I'm interested in whether there's a simple formula for the minimum if $Q$ is not positive-definite or invertible, but is positive-semi-definite. For example, for some toy problems I've found that

$$
\lim_{\epsilon\to 0} b^T(A(Q + \epsilon I)^{-1}A^T)^{-1}b
$$

exists and is equal to $m$, but I couldn't find an expression that this limit is equal to, in terms of operations that standard linear algebra packages could do. I could of course find the minimum by evaluating this expression for a small $\epsilon$, but that's quite unsatisfying.

Since this has a pseudo-inversey flavor, I've tried a few things with them, but none of these get the same minimum, e.g.

$$
m\ne b^T(AQ^{+}A^T)^+b
$$

and

$$
m \ne b^T(A^+)^TQA^+b.
$$

Is anyone familiar with a closed-form way to evaluate this limit, or with some other expression for $m$ with non-positive-definite $Q$? It feels like there's something obvious here that I haven't hit yet.

Comment: I added some background on the Lagrange multiplier-based solution for the QP in the case where Q is invertible. I'm still interested though in what we can compute in closed form when Q is not invertible.

Comment: Why use matrix inversion instead of Gaussian elimination?

Comment: Continuing on what @RodrigodeAzevedo said, to solve the problem, all you need is *one* KKT point. So you need to obtain any solution of the linear system. Using gaussian elimination, you can easily find one such solution.

Comment: Thanks, all. I am willing to assume that
$$\left(\begin{array}{cc}Q & A^T \\ A & 0\end{array}\right)$$ is invertible, and so backing up a step, I can get $x^*$ from the Lagrange formulation, and putting this into the objective function, that
$$m = \left(\begin{array}{c} 0 \\ b\end{array}\right)^T \left(\begin{array}{cc} Q & A^T \\ A & 0\end{array}\right)^{-1}
\left(\begin{array}{cc} Q & 0 \\ 0 & 0\end{array}\right)
\left(\begin{array}{cc} Q & A^T \\ A & 0\end{array}\right)^{-1}
\left(\begin{array}{c} 0 \\ b\end{array}\right).$$

Comment: So it does seem that in the case where $Q$ is not invertible but this augmented matrix is, the limit is
$$
\lim_{\epsilon\to 0} b^T(A(Q + \epsilon I)^{-1}A^T)^{-1}b =
\left(\begin{array}{c} 0 \\ b\end{array}\right)^T \left(\begin{array}{cc} Q & A^T \\ A & 0\end{array}\right)^{-1}
\left(\begin{array}{cc} Q & 0 \\ 0 & 0\end{array}\right)
\left(\begin{array}{cc} Q & A^T \\ A & 0\end{array}\right)^{-1}
\left(\begin{array}{c} 0 \\ b\end{array}\right),$$
which is a somewhat interesting result, and I have no intuition for why you should be able to evaluate the limit this way except via the QP.

Comment: I think what I was getting at with the original question, but may have emphasized the wrong parts, was: if I had this LHS above, the limit, outside this quadratic programming context, how would I even think to evaluate it as the RHS?